# Primefaces Outputpanel deferred=true

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
<h:form id="linkpanel">
<p:commandLink id="TestPanle" value="Test" update="contentOutputPanelId"/>
</h:form>
...
<h:form id="reRenderForm">
 <p:outputPanel id="contentOutputPanelId" deferred="true"  style="padding:5px;">
  <ui:include src="/pages/test.xhtml"/>
</p:outputPanel>
<h:form>
```

When press I press commandLink button it will update and contentOutputPanelId and include test.xhtml. My doubt is without deferred="true" it will not include page when I press refresh page it works fine.Otherwise givent deferred="true" it works fine.

Comment: @mss arul When you are trying to update `contentOutputPanelId` your `contentOutputPanelId` is not loading. Is it the case here?

Answer (score 2):

You're justified in your suspicion:

`ui:include` is a *taghandler*, while `p:outputpanel` is a `UIComponent`. A taghandler is evaluated and resolved at *view-build time*, that is when the component tree of the view is being setup (basically, deciding what's actually going to *be* in the page). The component, on the other hand, is evaluated at *view-render*, which mostly just has to do with markup interpretation

What this means for you is that as at the time `ui:include` is being evaluated, the `p:outputPanel` is not in the picture and therefore, not able to affect its processing. The inclusion will happen.

Taghandlers are evaluated only on fresh-page loads however, not on postback, so it doesn't really matter anymore at that point